# How Much More Difficult Is to Guess the Pin in the Second Case with Respect to the First One.

Tags: probability

I have two probability problems that don't know how to solve. Anyone helps please?

**The first problem**

A royal flush is a hand consisting of ace, king, queen, jack, and ten all in the same suit. Approximately how many distinct hands showing a royal flush are there in a standard 52 card desk? Hint: the card order is matter.

A. 5

B. 50

C. 500

D. 5000

**SECOND PROBLEM**

A Cell Phone 4 Key Pin Can Be over the Digits or over the Digits plus the Pound and Star Keys. How Much More Difficult Is to Guess the Pin in the Second Case with Respect to the First One.

A. About twice

B. about 16 times

C. about 100 times

D. much more than 100 times

I don't know how to solve this problem. Anyone helps please?

Thanks

Comment: How many cards in a hand??

Comment: I guess 5? A royal flush is a hand consisting of ace, king, queen, jack, and ten, so I guess properly 5.

Comment: Is the hint on the first one correct?  Usually order does NOT matter for poker hands.

Comment: It matters for this question

Comment: @Brick Agreed.  Either it's incorrect, or it's not a hint: it's part of the problem definition.

Comment: For the second problem: In case 1 there are $10 possibilities for each digit which means $10^4$ possible combinations , and in case 2 there are $12^4$ possible combinations. The difficulty is therefore $\frac{12^{4}}{10^{4}} =$approximately twice so the answer is option A

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem: In case $1$ there are $10$ possibilities for each digit which means 10 possibilities for each digit which means $10^4$ possible combinations, and in case $2$ there are $12^4$ possible combinations.The difficulty ratio is then given by $\frac{12^{4}}{10^{4}}$ which is roughly $2$, so the answer is $A$

Comment: how do you know there will be 10 possibilities?

Comment: Each entry can be $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ or $9$ which is a total of 10 possibilities. In case 2, there are $10 +2$ possibilities for each entry